# Cypress cannot find a test in spec file

Tags: javascript, cypress

Hope someone can help me with the spec file i'm trying to run:

```
describe('first visit', () => {
  it('Visiting login page', () => {
    cy.visit('<url here>')
    cy.get('div#username_container').should('be.visible')  
})
})
```

but cypress running is keep telling me that there are no any tests.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the name of this file and where is located in your project?

Comment: starting from the project root, file is  cypress/integration/3-dashboard-sample/login.spec.js

Comment: Please post your `cypress.json` file.

Comment: it's just empty, {} - that all it has

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I didn't know that the Atom IDE doesn't save a file on the fly and you need to save file explicitly before running it. So actually I tried to run an empty file. Everything went well after saving it.